# PHP interface in extended class not recognized as instance

Tags: php, oop, interface, extends, instanceof

I have an abstract class `A` which is extended by class `B` which implements the interface `I`.

```
abstract class A {
  public function test(){
    return $this->getX();
  }
  abstract protected function getX();
}

class B extends A implements I {
  public function Test() {
    $x = this->getX();
    if (!$x instanceof I) {
      throw new RuntimeException("not an instance of I");
    }
  }

  public function getX() {
    $aCoordinates = array('x' => 1, 'y' => 4, 'z' => 5); 
    return $aCoordinates;
  }
}

interface I {}
```

The `RuntimeException` is always thrown, despite `$x` is an instance of `I`. Anyone an idea why this happens?

`getX()` returns an array. `getX()` is just an example for a function returning an array.

Comment: If I look at this correctly, $x here will be set to 10, which is not an instance of I, but just a normal integer, right?

Comment: I've updated my example code. Actually $x ist just the result of getX()

Comment: What does getX return? Whatever it is, it's not an instance of I either

Comment: @Jake we need to see what getX() returns to help you.

Comment: ok, I've updated the question again. getX just returns an array of data.

Comment: @Jake if $x = getX(), therefore $x = array. An array is not an instance of your interface. This is why your exception is being thrown.

Comment: ok, so $x should be an object. Maybe I have to create an array containing objects. The code is not from me, so I try to figure out what it's doing.

Comment: @Jake Yes that's correct, $x will need to be an object. As an example, $x could be an instance of your class 'B'. Keep in mind that an array of objects will still be considered an array and not an instance of your interface

Answer (score 1):

The `getX()` method doesn't return any data So the value of `$x` is `null;` to have an object instance of I interface you need to put `return $this` in `getX()` method.

Comment: actually it does. I just forgot it in the example code.

Comment: Now `getX()` returns an array and of course its not instance of I interface. You need put `return $this;` instead of `return $aCoordinates;`